# mouseenter and mouseleave in javascript not working

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am having issue with the mouseenter and the mouseleave event in javascript. The strange thing is that the code works if you substitute these 2 events with click or dblclick events. Hope you can help me here. 
PS: I'm using chrome. 
don't know how to make js work on fiddle... for now

here's the code:

https://jsfiddle.net/frempong69/t7du0kte/

```
(function() {
  window.onload = function() {
    var box = document.getElementsByClassName("box")[0];

    var change = function() {
      box.style.backgroundColor = "green";
    };

    var normal = function() {
      box.style.backgroundColor = "blue";
    }

    addEventListener("click", change, false);
    addEventListener("mouseleave", normal, false);
  };

}());
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are adding the [mouseleave](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events/mouseleave)/[mouseenter](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events/mouseenter) handlers to the `window` object. The [click](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events/click) handler works because it bubbles to the window object, but the [mouseenter](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events/mouseenter) and [mouseleave](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events/mouseleave) events doesn't bubble so the listeners attached to the window object won't get triggered

You need add the listerns to the box element

```js
(function() {
  window.onload = function() {
    var box = document.getElementsByClassName("box")[0];

    var change = function() {
      box.style.backgroundColor = "green";
    };

    var normal = function() {
      box.style.backgroundColor = "blue";
    }

    box.addEventListener("mouseenter", change, false);
    box.addEventListener("mouseleave", normal, false);
  };


}());
```

```css
.box {
  background-color: red;
  width: 400px;
  height: 200px;
  margin: 50px auto;
  position: relative;
}
.box:after {
  content: " ";
  width: 0px;
  height: 0px;
  border-top: 100px solid transparent;
  border-right: 100px solid transparent;
  border-bottom: 100px solid transparent;
  border-left: 100px solid red;
  position: absolute;
  left: 100%;
  top: 50%;
  margin-top: -100px
}
```

```html
<div class="box">
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can simply do like this

```
 box.onmouseenter = change;
 box.mouseleave = normal;
```

Answer (score 0):

You must change

```
addEventListener("click", change, false);
addEventListener("mouseleave", normal, false);
```

with this

```
box.addEventListener("click", change, false);
box.addEventListener("mouseout", normal, false);
```

Answer (score -1):

you just use this

```
<div class="box" onmouseover="style.background='green'" onmouseout="style.background='red'">
</div>
```

its work

Comment: Before anyone chooses to [recommend deletion](http://stackoverflow.com/review/low-quality-posts/11115882) of this post, this is a valid attempted answer. This post should not have been flagged and should not be recommended for deletion in the LQPRQ. See: [You're doing it wrong: A plea for sanity in the Low Quality Posts queue](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/287563) and [Your answer is in another castle: when is an answer not an answer?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/225370)